# Adding services to a user using multiple selections in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-relationship, selectlist, multiple-select

I have a problem and don't know where to start as I am new to MVC. I have three tables:

- **User** (UserID, Username, etc...) *This defines users.*
- **Service** (ServiceID, ServiceName, etc...) *This defines services.*
- **Licenses** (ID, UserID, ServiceID, etc...) *Maps services to a user.*

In the back-end the user can access a service if he has a license. Ideally I would like a list of services in my EditUser view where I could check which services they should have licenses to.

This list needs to pre-populate with current licenses and if one is unchecked and saved it needs to be deleted.

I have all the methods to add and remove licenses, but I need to know how to implement this in my controller and view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, define a ViewModel

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IList<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

A View Model is simply a helper class that contains everything that you'll need to display a view. Then, in your action:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
{
    var userViewModel = new EditUserViewModel
    {
        User = // Get user from db
        Licenses = // Get licenses for that user
        Services = // Getservies the user in entitled to   
    }

    return View(userViewModel); 
}
```

Then, make your view a typed view with EditUserViewModel for model:

```
@model EditUserViewModel

@* //Some html or whatever here *@

@* //Access your model properties as follows *@
@Model.User
@Model.Licenses
@Model.Service
```

You can reuse the EditUserViewModel class for other views, UserDetails, for instance. In that case you might want to rename and get rid of the "Edit" prefix.

**UPDATE to clarify question in comments:**
Rule of thumb: Keep your view models small, dumb and simple. No methods, functionality or intelligence, just a couple of properties that assist you in the display process. You'll only want to reuse View Models on views that are very similar, like would be the case with an `EditUser` and `DisplayUser` view. You'd have a different view model for a `DisplayServices` view, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. View models are the way forward. Is it better to have a single view model that has everything in it or many specific view models for each different view?

Comment: @TheGwa - You're welcome. You'll probably end up having several view models because it is unlikely that wat is good for an EditUser view will be good for an EditServices view. Rule of thumb: Keep them small, dumb and simple. No methods, functionality or intelligence, just a couple of properties that assist you in the display process.